# Creating SortedDictionary with LinkedList value

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

I have a class called "OrderItem" and a list of the class's instances.
Now I want to create a SortedDictionary that the key would be one of the class properties and value of LinkedList that all of the items in the LinkedList will have the same key property.
I want to write a code same as this:

```
SortedDictionary<Double, LinkedList<OrderItem>> UnitPriceIndex;
foreach (OrderItem item in Data) // Data = list with all the instances of " OrderItem "
{ 
    UnitPriceIndex.Add(item.UnitPrice, LinkedList.add(item) // all items in the list will have the same UnitPrice
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You first have to check if the item is already present in the dictionary.  If it is then add it to the existing list, if not then add a new entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the key exists first. If it doesn't, then create it and assign a new list as value.

Then you can just add the current item to the LinkedList. For example:

```
var UnitPriceIndex = new SortedDictionary<double, LinkedList<OrderItem>>();

foreach (OrderItem item in Data)
{
    // Make sure the key exists. If it doesn't, add it 
    // along with a new LinkedList<OrderItem> as the value
    if (!UnitPriceIndex.ContainsKey(item.UnitPrice))
    {
        UnitPriceIndex.Add(item.UnitPrice, new LinkedList<OrderItem>());
    }

    UnitPriceIndex[item.UnitPrice].AddLast(item);
}
```